# how call OwlCarousel react Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, owl-carousel

Hi I use OwlCarousel React and I need call Method
but I don't any idea to call  the Method
please help me
https://github.com/laurenchen0631/react-owl-carousel

Comment: how call OwlCarousel Method?

Comment: https://github.com/laurenchen0631/react-owl-carousel/issues/28#issuecomment-544105556 look at this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step 1 - In your constructor create the options object which will be passed to OwnCaroussel in step 2

constructor() { super(); this.options = { onInitialized: function(){ this.carousel = this; } };

Step 2 - Pass options to OwlCarousel as follows
<OwlCarousel {...this.options}>

Step 3 - now you can call any of carousel's methods - For an example -

this.carousel.next() or this.carousel.prev() etc.

Answer (score 0):

for calling a method of OwlCarousel you should put ref on react OwlCarousel element and append it to this then call method on this
for example:

```
export class Owldemo1 extends Component {
click = ()=>{
    console.log(this.slider);
    this.slider.next(500)
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.click} className="btn btn-info">
                salam
            </button>
            <OwlCarousel items={5}
                         className="owl-theme"
                         loop
                         nav
                         margin={10}
                         ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)}
            >
                <div><img className="img" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/1/200/300"/></div>
                <div><img className="img" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/2/200/300"/></div>
                <div><img className="img" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/4/200/300"/></div>
                <div><img className="img" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/3/200/300"/></div>
                <div><img className="img" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/5/200/300"/></div>
                <div><img className="img" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/6/200/300"/></div>
                <div><img className="img" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/7/200/300"/></div>
            </OwlCarousel>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}